# how to index google docs to google search engine?

Tags: google-chrome

I am going to create a spreadsheet in google docs but there is problem in my work. 
I want to index mine spreadsheet which i will create in future to index google search engine so that its result include in search engine. i have search a lot on web but i don't get nothing. 
i have found some information is here http://www.labnol.org/internet/your-google-docs-in-search-engines/9590/
but that is not working for me.
can anybody help me??

If you want to check what i want than

```
1-search "csk vs rr head to head" on google.com
2- you will find 3rd result of google docs.
```

i also want that my docs apear in search results.